# How do I force a VMWare Windows XP virtual machine to shut down?

Tags: windows, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP hangs when shutting down in VMWare Fusion](https://superuser.com/questions/23755/windows-xp-hangs-when-shutting-down-in-vmware-fusion)

I’ve got a VMWare virtual machine running Windows XP (SP3). It seems to be stuck on the Windows XP shutdown screen, installing Windows updates.

It’s been installing update 1 of 2, and telling me not to shut it down, for a few hours now. Two other Windows XP VMs on the same physical machine have successfully installed the updates.

VMWare won’t shut down the VM via the Virtual Machine > Shut Down Guest menu option. I’m running VMWare on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard, 10.6.4).

Is there any way I can force it to quit?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, this worked: [Windows XP hangs when shutting down in VMWare Fusion](https://superuser.com/questions/23755/windows-xp-hangs-when-shutting-down-in-vmware-fusion/29430#29430)