# Windows XP never quits VMWare Fusion, how to shut it down?

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, vmware-fusion

One Windows XP VM keeps looping the following 2 screens:

[image]
[image]

Even I force-quit VMWare, next time VMWare restarts, it's the same screen. How can I shutdown the XP inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows XP hangs when shutting down in VMWare Fusion](https://superuser.com/questions/23755/windows-xp-hangs-when-shutting-down-in-vmware-fusion)